# Laravel websockets failed after reinstall npm

Tags: laravel, npm, websocket

I was using `Laravel websockets` and it worked fine till last night I did `remove **node_modules** folder and **package-lock.json** file` for some reasons.

I used these commands after that:

```
npm install

npm run dev
```

I expect that everything workes like before because I removed all changes.

But know there's log message in console without any try and immediately after page load with this message:

[image: console message picture]

**This is my echo setting, Just for information:**

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    wssPort: 6001,
    disableStats: true,
    encrypted: false,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss']
});
```

***UPDATE :***

I did clean `npm cache` using `npm cache clean --force` and did above scenario again but there's no difference in result.

Does anyone knnow where's my mistake?

***Thanks in Advance***

Answer (score 0):

By removing the `package-lock.json` file you are now using different versions of all packages (within the constraints of your `package.json` file). You could solve this by:

1. Restoring `package-lock.json`
2. Removing `node_modules`
3. Run `npm install`
4. Run `npm run dev`

This will install the verious which you previously had since the the lock file is used exactly for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks but I can't restore `package-lock.json`, I deleted that file :-|